# Using Spring Boot application to pull key value pairs from Spring Cloud Consul

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-consul

After referencing this link, I am able to pull down value from config/application/key1

The code are as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@RestController
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Application {

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String home() {
    return env.getProperty("keys");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(true).run(args);
  }

}
```

- However, may I ask how to access `key1` value in the path of `config/application/keys/key1` (one level deeper)?
- And if there is the repetition in the like `config/application.key1` and `config/software/key1`, how can I choose which one to pull down?